# CSS spacing using the :before pseudo attribute

Tags: css

I have an image that I'm trying to place using :before. I want the image to sit on the first letter of the line. If you look at the live site, The bird's feet should touch the letter "C".
It works in the fiddle, but not on the live site. Any help?

http://imip.rvadv.com/index3.html

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/imakeitpretty/yV3kK/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding

```
.st-accordion ul li > a{
   line-height:27px;
   ...
}
```

And updating the following:

```
#chirp:before {
    ...
    margin-bottom:0;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This not only worked for that issue, but solved an entirely different issue I was having! you are wonderful!

Answer (score 2):

```
#chirp:before{
margin-bottom:-20px;
}
```

Currently, the margin-bottom is set to -10px;

Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked, but the @Liggy's solution worked better by solving what I thought was an unrelated issue. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You are using different base css on jsfiddle and your test site.

For example, the font-family is already different so you can't really compare the two.

Anyways, setting `margin-bottom` to `-20px` in `#chirp:before` solves your problem.

Comment: This worked, but the @Liggy's solution worked better by solving what I thought was an unrelated issue. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can try ositioning the :before element with absolute:

http://jsfiddle.net/yV3kK/31/

```
#chirp:before {
    content:url(http://imip.rvadv.com/images/chirp-bird.png);
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    width: 77px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -44px; 
    left: -35px;
}

#chirp{
    position:relative;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a `line-height` issue to me. Try setting it to `36px` (the same as your font size). I'm not sure *why* it's happening, but I suspect that the line height for text is different on your site and JSFiddle.